# What package-info do I annotate with XmlJavaTypeAdapters?

Tags: java, jaxb

I've studied [Blaise Doughan's answer to a question on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687188/how-to-convert-dateactionscript-3-to-java-util-date-through-a-xml/4694496#4694496) but have a further question.

`XmlJavaTypeAdapters` lets you list a bunch of `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations, each of which governs how a non-bindable type is mapped to a bindable type by JAXB.

You can use this annotation at the package level.  When you do so, every `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation needs its `type()` attribute fully specified.

There does not appear to be a requirement that the package that is being annotated have anything to do with the package of the non-bindable types being adapted.  That is convenient and nice.

That, however, leads me to my next question: if there is no relationship between the annotated package and the package of the type being adapted, how does JAXB discover package-level `XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotations?  How, in other words, does it know which packages to consult for potential `XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotations?  May I make a random package in, say, a `.jar` file in my `.ear` file's `lib` directory that contains a single, ginormous `package-info` class that is annotated with all the adapters for all of my non-bindable types?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the JAXB runtime loads a JAXB-annotated class, it looks for a `package-info.java` in the same package as that class, and checks that to look for package-level annotations. So while `XmlJavaTypeAdapters` doesn't have to reside in the same package as the "non-bindable" types, it *does* have to reside in the same package as the "bindable" types.

For example, say I have a JAXB-annotated class `A`, in package `X`, which has a property of  type `B` in package `Y`. In order to bind the `B` property, let's say a type adapter is required. That adapter can be specified in `A` itself, or it can be specified in the `package-info.java` in package `X`. Package `Y` is pretty much arbitrary, and is of no interest to the JAXB runtime.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Very helpful; thanks. Does the graph get walked from there?  That is, suppose I have a single bindable type that I feed to JAXB.  Suppose further that his package is annotated with 647 `XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotations, each of which specifies a non-bindable type and an adapter for that type. Would my `JAXBContext` now be able to handle all 647 now-adapted types?

Comment: @Laird: Yes, as long as (a) you had the RAM to handle it, and (b) All of the bindable types were in that package.

Comment: Interesting.  Seems odd that I'd have to bootstrap the whole process, though.  I mean, if I can set up a pile of adapters by simply feeding JAXB a single type, then I would hope it should be possible to improve JAXB so that that single type wouldn't be necessary either.  Like have JAXB look by default for a "root" `package-info` somewhere so that the initial bootstrapping isn't necessary.  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 5):

> There does not appear to be a requirement that the package that is
>   being annotated have anything to do with the package of the
>   non-bindable types being adapted. That is convenient and nice.

This is correct.  When `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` is used at the package level it means apply this adapter to all properties of the specified type for classes that reside in this package.  I'll demonstrate below with an example.

**forum8735737.bar.package-info**

For this package we will specify an `XmlAdapter` that will be applied to all fields/properties of type `String` within this package.

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
})
package forum8735737.bar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

**forum8735737.bar.StringAdapter**

Our `XmlAdapter` will simply convert all instances of `String` to upper case when marshalling:

```
package forum8735737.bar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        if(null == v) {
            return v;
        }
        return v.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

**forum8735737.bar.Bar**

`Bar` represents a POJO in this package with a property of type `String`:

```
package forum8735737.bar;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Bar {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**forum8735737.foo.Foo**

Foo represents a domain object with a property of type `String` that exists in a different package.  The `XmlAdapter` we registered for the `forum8735737.bar` package will not apply to this class:

```
package forum8735737.foo;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

The following code will create instances of both `Foo` and `Bar` and marshal them to XML:

```
package forum8735737;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

import forum8735737.bar.Bar;
import forum8735737.foo.Foo;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setName("Foo");
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);

        Bar bar = new Bar();
        bar.setName("Bar");
        marshaller.marshal(bar, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Notice how the value of the `name` element within `bar` has been converted to upper case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo>
   <name>Foo</name>
</foo>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar>
   <name>BAR</name>
</bar>
```

Comment: Blaise, is there any way to get this working for a package that you don't have the source code for?